# Get url part only in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table data is looks like:

```
SessionRefere  

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=aaa bbb&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://www.abc.com/&ei=QFR0UM-JKIrQrQfsuoG4CQ&usg=AFQjCNExYcKkcvobBbktLGNksptf1giQRw
-------------------------------------------------
http://www.google.com/reader/view/?hl=es&tab=Xq&at=RTknd_lBUUnvNqan2641EA
----------------------------------------------------
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEgQFjAE&url=http://www.abc.com/ppp.aspx&ei=dmd0UOO9AYnY4QS1sYGwBw&usg=AFQjCNGIFcJUUSVpl_ZiZoSWDP2LkIagtw
```

It's only sample data.There are many cases like this. So I want original url part before count.

I use this query to get data.

```
DECLARE @temp table(RefPage nvarchar(200))
insert into @temp
SELECT
   CASE CHARINDEX( '?', SessionReferer)
       WHEN 0 THEN SessionReferer
       ELSE LEFT(SessionReferer, CHARINDEX( '?', SessionReferer) - 1) END AS RefPage 
FROM Tracker WHERE [start] between '1-1-2010' and '1-1-2015' and  SessionReferer<> ''

 select distinct RefPage, count(*) as [VisitTime] from @temp
  group by RefPage
order by [VisitTime] desc
```

and my result is:

```
SessionRefere                           VisitTime
http://www.google.com/url                 2
http://www.google.com/reader/view/        1
```

But I want a result:

```
SessionRefere                           VisitTime
http://www.google.com                      3
```

Is it possible to get desire result or I am in wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: is it important for you to do truncate the url with SQL only?

Comment: Yap I want it in ms-sql.

Comment: Ok. you may want to checkout this post (especially the first scenario http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1325/parsing-a-url-with-sql-server-functions/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting at `CHARINDEX('/',SessionReferrer,9)`

```
 select 
   case when CHARINDEX('/',SessionReferrer,9) = 0 
     then SessionReferrer
     else left(SessionReferrer, CHARINDEX('/',SessionReferrer,9)-1)
   end,
   count(*)
 from Tracker      
 group by
   case when CHARINDEX('/',SessionReferrer,9) = 0 
     then SessionReferrer
     else left(SessionReferrer, CHARINDEX('/',SessionReferrer,9)-1)
   end
```

(I am lazily assuming all your referrers start with http:// or https://)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Declare @T Table(URL Varchar(MAX))
Insert Into @T Values('http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=aaa bbb&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://www.abc.com/&ei=QFR0UM-JKIrQrQfsuoG4CQ&usg=AFQjCNExYcKkcvobBbktLGNksptf1giQRw')
Insert Into @T Values('http://www.google.com/reader/view/?hl=es&tab=Xq&at=RTknd_lBUUnvNqan2641EA')
Insert Into @T Values('http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEgQFjAE&url=http://www.abc.com/ppp.aspx&ei=dmd0UOO9AYnY4QS1sYGwBw&usg=AFQjCNGIFcJUUSVpl_ZiZoSWDP2LkIagtw')
Insert Into @T Values('http://www.yahoo.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEgQFjAE&url=http://www.abc.com/ppp.aspx&ei=dmd0UOO9AYnY4QS1sYGwBw&usg=AFQjCNGIFcJUUSVpl_ZiZoSWDP2LkIagtw')

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        URL
        ,SessionRefere = SUBSTRING(URL,0,CHARINDEX('://', URL)+3) + SUBSTRING(URL,CHARINDEX('://', URL)+3,CHARINDEX('/', SUBSTRING(URL,CHARINDEX('://', URL)+3,LEN(URL)))-1)
    FROM @T
)

SELECT SessionRefere,[VisitTime] = COUNT(SessionRefere)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY SessionRefere
```

**Output**

```
SessionRefere   VisitTime
http://www.google.com   3
http://www.yahoo.com    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am doing:

for  a string  @test:
I am splitting the string between '//' and '/' from the URL 
and  concatinating http: or https  according to given URL

```
Declare  @test nvarchar(100)
Declare @http nvarchar(8)
set @test = 'http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=aaa bbb&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://www.abc.com/&ei=QFR0UM-JKIrQrQfsuoG4CQ&usg=AFQjCNExYcKkcvobBbktLGNksptf1giQRw'
declare @length int
declare @start int
declare @subString nvarchar(100)
set @start =( select CharIndex('//', @test))
set @http = SUBSTRING(@test, 0 , @start)
set @length = Len(@test)
set @subString = SUBSTRING ( @test ,@start+2 , @length )
set @start =( select CharIndex('/', @subString))
set @subString = SUBSTRING ( @subString ,0 , @start )
set @subString = @http+'//'+ @subString
```