# Extract hostname from a URL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to trim the website name upto ".com" or"co.in" in sql

example: lets assume i have  site address as"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=trim".
I need to get the result as "stackoverflow.com".

some scenario it may be like "www.google.co.in" then i need it to be "google.co.in"

Comment: @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815258/get-url-part-only-in-sql-server (though that question wants the protocol, so not an exact duplicate)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please use the below SQL code to extract the domain name:

```
DECLARE @WebUrl VARCHAR(35);
SET @WebUrl = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=trim'

SELECT @WebUrl AS 'WebsiteURL',
       LEFT(SUBSTRING(@WebUrl, 
       (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('//',@WebUrl)=0 
            THEN 5 
            ELSE  CHARINDEX('//',@WebUrl) + 2
            END), 35),
       (CASE 
       WHEN CHARINDEX('/', SUBSTRING(@WebUrl, CHARINDEX('//', @WebUrl) + 2, 35))=0 
       THEN LEN(@WebUrl) 
       else CHARINDEX('/', SUBSTRING(@WebUrl, CHARINDEX('//', @WebUrl) + 2, 35))- 1
       END)
       ) AS 'Domain';
```

Comment: Thanks deepak,but how will it work if the url is like"www.google.co.in" ?.

Comment: I have found a case scenario that this does not workout very well here is the result for this case scenario I'm talking about:

{
  "RAW_URL": "http://some-site.subdomain.com/?ad=123&p=test&http://some-site.subdomain.com/?ad=123&p=test&gclid=XXX",
  "Domain": "some-site.subdomain.co",
}

@Fenton 's solution works better and gives the correct domain url

Answer (score 8):

I found that there can be a lot of variation here, especially when running against a table of referrers. For this reason I created a [SQL script that gets the host name from a web address](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/09/select-the-host-name-from-a-string-in-sql/) that also covers all of the edge cases I found.

```
DECLARE @WebAddress varchar(300) = 'https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/09/select-the-host-name-from-a-string-in-sql/'
SELECT 
    /* Get just the host name from a URL */
    SUBSTRING(@WebAddress,
        /* Starting Position (After any '//') */
        (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress)= 0 THEN 1 ELSE CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2 END),
        /* Length (ending on first '/' or on a '?') */
        CASE
            WHEN CHARINDEX('/', @WebAddress, CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('/', @WebAddress, CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2) - (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress)= 0 THEN 1 ELSE CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2 END)
            WHEN CHARINDEX('?', @WebAddress, CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('?', @WebAddress, CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2) - (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress)= 0 THEN 1 ELSE CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2 END)
            ELSE LEN(@WebAddress)
        END
    ) AS 'HostName'
```

This will handle...

- An address starting `www.` (i.e. no scheme)
- A address starting `//`
- Host names that terminate with a `/`
- Host names that terminate with a query string

Comment: Worked well for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
SELECT
    `url` ,
    LEFT(
        RIGHT(
            `url` ,
            length(`url`) -(position('//' IN `url`) + 1)
        ) ,
        position(
            '/' IN RIGHT(
                `url` ,
                length(`url`) -(position('//' IN `url`) + 1)
            )
        ) - 1
    ) AS domain
FROM
    `test`;
```

[Extract domain name from a URL](https://eikhart.com/blog/mysql-extract-domain-name)

Comment: If you want the domain without the subdomain www you can use this code:
if (url like '%//www.%',length(`url`) -(position('//' IN `url`) + 5), length(`url`) -(position('//' IN `url`) + 1))

Answer (score 1):

Use SQLCLR function and leverage the [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I was trying to do this recently and the answers here ether did not cover strings starting with `http/s` or the new gTLDs. So here is what I came up with using CTE expressions to try and keep it as readable and understandable as possible.

Hopefully it will help anyone stumbling upon this thread in the future!

```
DECLARE @Var NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @Var='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=trim';

WITH cteWithoutWWW (Domain)
as
(
    SELECT
      case when PATINDEX('%www.%', @Var) > 0 then
            SUBSTRING(@Var, PATINDEX('%www.%', @Var) + 4, LEN(@Var) - PATINDEX('%www.%', @Var))
      else
            @Var
      end
),
cteWithoutHTTP (Domain)
as
(
      select
      case when PATINDEX('http://%', Domain) > 0 then
            SUBSTRING(Domain, PATINDEX('http://%', Domain) + 7, LEN(Domain) - PATINDEX('http://%', Domain))
      else
            Domain
      end
      from cteWithoutWWW
),
cteWithoutSlash (Domain)
as
(
      select
      case when CHARINDEX('/', Domain) > 0 then
            SUBSTRING(Domain, 0, CHARINDEX('/', Domain))
      else
            Domain
      end
      from cteWithoutHTTP
)
select Domain from cteWithoutSlash
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @Var NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @Var='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=trim'

SET @Var=REPLACE(@Var,'http://','')
IF(LEFT(@Var,4)='www.')
    SET @Var=RIGHT(@Var, len(@Var)-4)

IF(PATINDEX('%.com%', @Var)<>0)
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Var,0, PATINDEX('%.com%', @Var)+4)
ELSE IF (PATINDEX('%.co.%', @Var)<>0)
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Var,0, PATINDEX('%.co.%', @Var)+6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I built this function to do that

```
ALTER FUNCTION fnHostName
(
    @URL varchar(4000)
)
RETURNS varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN


declare @Dot int
declare @Slash int

set @Dot = CHARINDEX('.', @URL)
set @Slash = CHARINDEX('/', @URL)

WHILE @Slash > 0 AND @Slash < @Dot
BEGIN
    SET @URL = SUBSTRING(@URL,@Slash+1, LEN(@URL))
    set @Dot = CHARINDEX('.', @URL)
    set @Slash = CHARINDEX('/', @URL)
END

IF @Slash > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @URL = LEFT(@URL, @Slash-1)
END

RETURN @URL



END

GO
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code,
use substring. It will work for both .com and .co.in

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(50),  @ind int = 0
SET @string = 'http://stackoverflow.co.in/questions/ask?title=trim'


SET @ind=  charindex('.com', @string)  

IF @ind = 0
BEGIN
    SET @ind=  charindex('.co.in', @string)  
    Print SUBSTRING ( @string ,0 , @ind+6 )
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Print SUBSTRING ( @string ,0 , @ind +4)
END
```