# I need a SQL query that will return the URLs in my table with https:// and / or www. removed

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a query on a table to return the URL of different organizations and I am trying to remove any instance of 'https://', 'http://' AND 'www.' at the beginning, and any '/' at the end

So for example if I have a URL that is currently returning `'https://www.pizzatest.com/'` and I need it to just be `pizzatest.com`

This is for importing organization domains into Zendesk

I have found a query that works for removing https:// and http:// and any / or ? at the end of the URL, but I can not seem to figure out how to remove the 'www.' from the beginning.

The query was taken from this question here - credit to [Fenton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75525/fenton)
[Extract hostname from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266534/extract-hostname-from-a-url/32559759#32559759)

```
/* Get just the host name from a URL */     SUBSTRING(@WebAddress,         /* Starting Position (After any '//') */         (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress)= 0 THEN 1 ELSE CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2 END),         /* Length (ending on first '/' or on a '?') */         CASE             WHEN CHARINDEX('/', @WebAddress, CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('/', @WebAddress, CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2) - (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress)= 0 THEN 1 ELSE CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2 END)             WHEN CHARINDEX('?', @WebAddress, CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('?', @WebAddress, CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2) - (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress)= 0 THEN 1 ELSE CHARINDEX('//', @WebAddress) + 2 END)             ELSE LEN(@WebAddress)         END     ) AS 'HostName'
```

Comment: i would look for a REGEX statement that does what you want, not a string parser by hand this way

Comment: What's the significance of the (non-formatted) wall of code that isn't valid for Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regexp_replace() to remove the different parts, then use `trim()` to get rid of any leading of trailing `/`

```
trim(regexp_replace(the_column, '(http://)|(https://)|(www.)', '', 'g'), '/')
```

Comment: This did work for any URL that was ending in a '/'. However there are some URLs that have characters after the '/' that would also need to be removed